# Django REST Framework error with accepted_renderer

Tags: rest, api, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty noob with DFR so I'm learning by following the tutorial.
Until now all is fine, but in the last part, [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/7-schemas-and-client-libraries/#adding-a-schema), I have to add a schema to the API and I follow the instructions, so install coreapi and add

```
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

schema_view = get_schema_view(title='Pastebin API')

urlpatterns = [
    path('schema/', schema_view),
    ...
]
```

in tutorial/urls.py, so my complete tutorial/urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

schema_view = get_schema_view(title='Pastebin API')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('snippets.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('schema/', schema_view),
]
```

But if I visit /schema/ from browser at http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/, I get:

```
AttributeError at /schema/

'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'
```

I do not understand how to fix this error since I followed the tutorial's instructions.

My conf is:

```
coreapi             2.3.3     
coreschema          0.0.4     
Django              2.1.3     
djangorestframework 3.9.0
```

If needed you can see the tutorial's code [here](https://github.com/encode/rest-framework-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/urls.py) and [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#the-get_schema_view-shortcut) is the get_schema_view documentation.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6331 using DRF 3.8.0 instead of 3.9.0

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions:

install pyyaml:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

**OR**

Revert DRF:

```
pip install djangorestframework==3.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial makes a request to that endpoint from the command-line using [HTTPie](https://httpie.org), not the browser which would require a renderer to be specified. If you want this to work from the browser, specify a renderer as the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#renderer_classes) describes

Comment: The tutorial say: If you visit the /schema/ endpoint in a browser you should now see corejson representation become available as an option.

Comment: No it doesn't, I've looked at the docs for `get_schema_view` in the tutorial and your link, it states `Once the view has been added, you'll be able to make API requests to retrieve the auto-generated schema definition.`

Followed by a request using HTTPie.

Comment: Yes I know and I've already tried with httpie and get the same error. Moreover I have tested all the other endpoints (from previous part of the tutorial) both from the browser and from the command line and only this does not work. Please note that requests can come from both the browser and the command line.